# How do you handle using Appium to test both an iOS and an Android device with the same code?

Tags: c#, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

I notice they both have different drivers (at least for c# that I am using).

```
private AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> _driver;
private IOSDriver<IOSElement> _iosDriver;
```

How do you handle all the different locators etc. Do you write two versions of the code, one for iOS and the other for Android.
Would appreciate any advice you can offer.

I was hoping to create a method like:

```
internal void ClickOKButton(driver)
{
   driver.FindElementById("okBtn").Click();
}
```

and use the method as:

```
page.ClickOKButton(IOSElement> driver) <-- for iOS
page.ClickOKButton(AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> driver) <-- for Android
```

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give you an answer based on my experience with both Android and iOS projects, only that i've always used them seperately instead of the same project (Java based).

After analyzing both Appium Android and iOS projects, I have the following highlights. All these things can, with the right statements, be handled in the same project.:

*Sorry if this makes less sense in C#, but I hope this gives you an indication of the differences*

- Same NPM packages although iOS can only be executed on Mac OS X
- Drivers are different for iOS and Android:

```
AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap); <- for Android
IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap); <- for iOS
```

- Capabilities are different for iOS and Android (I have not specifically synchronized these throughout the different projects)

```
Android
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("noReset", true);
        cap.setCapability("app", APP);
        cap.setCapability("avd", EMULATOR);

iOS
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, deviceName);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "auto");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, platformVersion);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app);
        cap.setCapability("showXcodeLog", false);
```

- PageFactorys are different for Locators (I create a new Java class to make a library of Elements and make an instance in the Main)

```
Android - PageFactory for elements
    public Elements(AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@text,'text')]")
    public MobileElement element;

iOS - PageFactory for elements
    public Elements(IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    @iOSXCUITFindBy(xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='text']")
    public MobileElement element;
```

- WebDriverWaits are the same

```
wait_5 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
```